# Issues locating start/end times with protractor

Tags: protractor

I am having issues locating the text of start and end times on our web application using page objects. Below is the code, the only thing that will change is the time (in between `::before` and `::after`).

How can I locate the class in the page object?

```
<dd ng-class="pdfView ? 'col-xs-9' : ''" class="byt-start-time ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="!byt.bytID.timeStartText">9:00 PM</dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the given HTML, relying on a `byt-start-time` class should work:

```
var startTime = $(".byt-start-time");
startTime.getText().then(console.log);
```

Comment: I'm using `expect(itinerary.startTime.getText).toContain('8:00 AM'); itinerary.startTime.getText().then(console.log);` but receiving a failure:  Expected Function to contain '8:00 AM'. 8:00 AM is being logged correctly to the console, so I'm not sure why its still failing. Ideas?

Comment: @Kelsey  make sure to call `getText()` - notice the parenthesis. Thanks

Comment: @Kelsey hey, have you got it working eventually? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working. Either getText is not working correctly or I receive the error "A jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the webdriver control flow"- neither make sense because the correct value displays in the console.

Comment: @Kelsey okay, but have you tried calling the method as I've proposed: `expect(itinerary.startTime.getText()).toContain('8:00 AM'); `

Comment: That works, I had `expect(itinerary.startTime).toEqual('8:00 AM');` is there any reason why what I had wouldn't have worked?

Comment: @Kelsey let's see. How `itinerary.startTime` is defined?

Comment: startTime is identified by your recommendation and included in the page object file.

Comment: @Kelsey the important thing is - have you defined it as `$(".byt-start-time")` or `$(".byt-start-time").getText()`? Sorry for guesses, it's difficult to help without having the full picture in front. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63123/discussion-between-kelsey-and-alecxe).